# How to get Excel to ignore N/As

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, na

I have a nested if/or/and statement that otherwise works but gives me 'false' values if there are any N/As in the row. I want it to completely ignore the N/A (so, if I've asked it to tell me if `A2<3` and `B2<3`, and `A2=1` but `B2` contains `N/A`, I still want it to tell me the statement is 'true').

I've tried following help pages on how to deal with `N/As` but they either don't work or assign `N/As` different values. Please help!

Comment: Don't you need `=OR(ISNUMBER(A2:B2))*IFNA(A2<3,1)*IFNA(B2<3,1)` to return `0` (FALSE) for double `#N/A` values?

Comment: You could try using `TOCOL()` or `TOROW()` if you are using `MS365` --> `=AND(TOCOL(A2:B2,3)<3)`

Comment: That's actually real clever and likely the shortest

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting tripped up on the idea of *ignoring* which you really can't do as part of an [and function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9). However, you can get essentially the same result by converting any errors to `true` (though if all were ignored this might be a problem as it gives true -- see below illustration row 7).

As the other answers illustrate, there are a variety of ways to do this. My personal preference is to use an [iferror](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-iferror-function-formula-examples/) function in each condition which returns `true` when there's an error in the condition. So in your example formula

```
=And(iferror(A2<3,true),iferror(B2<3,true))
```

[image]

If you used this for each of the following rows, you'd get theses results (lookout for row 7... not sure how you'd handle it).

If you wanted the shortest possible formula, I think this is it (anyone make a shorter one?)

```
=iferror(A2<3,1)*iferror(B2<3,1)>0
```

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, thanks! Look at your rating! You were just a 2,000 a few months ago! (or at least that's what I remember). Can you get a shorter formula then the one I threw in at end?

Comment: I am in no rush sir, but sir edit : `=iferror(A2<3,1)*iferror(B2<3,1)>0` second `IFERROR()` shouldn't be `B2`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=AND(A2<3,IFERROR(B2<3+ISNA(B2),1))
```

---

Looking at this example below, to ignore the `#N/A` you would need an `IFERROR()` to parse the error to work with `BOOLEAN` values ie `TRUE` and `FALSE` where `TRUE` is `1` while `FALSE` is 0

[image]

---

**Note:** `+` operator used as `OR()` function, while `*` used as `AND()`.

---

Shortest alternative that I came up with using <kbd>TOCOL()</kbd> or <kbd>TOROW()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=AND(TOCOL(A2:B2,3)<3)
```

---

Or, if you have both the cells as `#N/A`

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(AND(TOCOL(A2:B2,3)<3),TRUE)
```

---

**Edit : 10/31/23 -- Formula Update:**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=AND(IFNA(A2:B2+0,0)<3)
```

---

Using Single Dynamic Array Formula --> <kbd>BYROW()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=BYROW(A2:B8,LAMBDA(α,AND(IFNA(α+0,0)<3)))
```

---

Comment: What is reason to use `=AND(A2<3,IFERROR(B2<3+ISNA(B2),1))` instead of `=AND(A2<3,IFERROR(B2<3,1))`?

Comment: @rotabor thats how i was constructing without copying from others while i was writing the post Steven Sir posted their solution. Also the screenshot explains abt the boolean. Now im trying a shorter approach.

Comment: So `=AND(A2<3,IFERROR(B2<3+ISNA(B2),1))` can be simplified to `=AND(A2<3,IFERROR(B2<3,1))`?

Comment: Yes I agree but like I said while I was posting the answer someone already posted so I had to change I cannot post a same answer

Comment: Thanks, I just want to get if I did miss something or not.

Comment: No you didnt do anything wrong, but you didnt tried the formula first in excel the one which commented and later deleted post, I know it was wrong `NOT(ISNA())` will not work. So I was writing the post and it took me long as I was watching cricket worldcup  & later had to wait for a min to change

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can also be fulfilled by combining the **IFNA** function with your existing formula. Hopefully, the following formula will help.

**Excel Formula**:

```
=IF(AND(IFNA(A2<3,TRUE),IFNA(B2<3,TRUE)),TRUE,FALSE)
```